# How do I install Rails on Windows 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I have a normal machine running Windows 10. What's the simplest way to install Ruby on Rails on it? I've found a few different guides online but they all give different instructions. I'm looking for the "official" way, if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically it's been pretty complicated, but on Windows 10 it's actually really simple. Just go [here](http://railsinstaller.org/en), and download your preferred edition of Ruby. It's a really straightforward installation process. At the end just check your Ruby and Rails versions to make sure everything's properly installed. I'm not sure if this is the "official" way, but it works and it's really simple.

Comment: RailsInstaller.org site is now dead.